# java.awt.geom.area is distubing or disappearing in java

Tags: java

I am using geom area in my java application. in this application i am doing that i am painting the area in JFrame then drawing dynamic rectangle in JFrame over geom area to subtract it however it works fine but some times it disappears when mouse is released or it disturbing when tooltip text displays over area.

Here is my Code.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setStroke(dashed);
//g.setColor(Color.red);
if(x1 ==0 && y1 == 0){
  g2.dispose();
  }
else{
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.draw(shape);
g2.setColor(Color.black);
Area area = new Area();

area.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())));

g2.setColor(Color.BLACK.brighter());

int width = getWidth() - 1;
int height = getHeight() - 1;

int openWidth = 200;
int openHeight = 200;

int x = (width - openWidth) / 2;
int y = (height - openHeight) / 2;


area.subtract(new Area(shape));



g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
g2.fill(area);
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));
g2.fillRect(x3-8, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3-8, (y3+height1/2)-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3-8, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect((x3+width1/2)-8, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect((x3+width1/2)-8, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, (y3+height1/2)-8, 8, 8);
g2.dispose();
```

}

}

Here shape is the Rectangle and it re-sizes dynamically through mouseListener when the mouseReleased function is called the area is disappears some time. also i used some buttons with tooltip text so whent the tooltip text is appears the area disturbs and looking awkward.

CropScreen.java

```
package Main;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class CropScreen extends JComponent
 implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
  static Point startPoint = new Point(), endPoint = new Point();
  private File movieFolder = null; 
  ActionListener a1,a2,a3,a4;    
  final JPanel panel =new JPanel();
  JPanel np =null,bp,im=null;
  String cl;
  Rectangle shape = null;
  JScrollPane sp=null;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JLabel mousePosition;
   int x, y,c=0,m=0;
   int x1, x2, y1, y2,x4,x5,y4,y5;
   int w, h,width,height,width2,height2;
   private JLabel recStart;
   private JLabel recStop;
   private JLabel cords;
   private int mousePressedX, mousePressedY; 
   private int width1;
   private int height1;
  int x3, y3;
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Edit Images");
   final static float dash1[] = { 2.0f };
   final static BasicStroke dashed = new BasicStroke(1.0f,
    BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, dash1, 0.0f);
    JButton blur,pencil,pencil1,clear,b,txt,saveedit,Pencil;

  Boolean etb = true;
 ImageIcon save = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/save.png"));
 ImageIcon close = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/close.png"));
 ImageIcon tool = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/tool.png"));
 ImageIcon browse = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/browse.png"));

 JButton jp,brows;
 Robot robot;
 JFrame window = null;

 JButton jp1;
 JButton but = new JButton();
 JPanel p = new JPanel();
 JPanel sz = new JPanel();
 JLabel size = new JLabel();
 MainIconPage d =null;
 CropScreen component;
 //
boolean dragging = false;

final int PROX_DIST = 3;

public CropScreen()
 {

   component = this;
   if(window == null)
        window = new JFrame("Edit Pane");
   if(d == null)
        d = new MainIconPage();
   pencil = new JButton(tool);
   pencil.setToolTipText("Edit Selected Area !");
   but.setEnabled(false);
   sz.add(but);

   sz.setVisible(true);
   d.main.add(but);

  p.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50,1));    
  d.main.add(p);

  //super( "Rectangle Drawer" );
 jp =new JButton(save);
 jp.setToolTipText("Save Selected Area !");
 jp1 = new JButton(close);
 jp1.setToolTipText("Close");
 brows = new JButton(browse);
 brows.setToolTipText("Browse Directory !");

 brows.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
 jp1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
 jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));     
 pencil.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
 p.add(jp);
 p.add(jp1);
 p.add(pencil);
 p.add(brows);
 p.setVisible(false);

  mousePosition = new JLabel();
  mousePosition.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  panel.add( mousePosition, BorderLayout.CENTER );


  JLabel text1 = new JLabel();
  text1.setText( "At the center the mouse pointer's coordinates will be displayed." );
  panel.add( text1, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

  recStart = new JLabel();
  panel.add(recStart, BorderLayout.WEST);

  recStop = new JLabel();
  panel.add(recStop, BorderLayout.EAST);

  cords = new JLabel();
  panel.add(cords, BorderLayout.NORTH);


  addMouseListener( this );        
  addMouseMotionListener( this );  





 }


public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent event )
{
   x1 = 0;
    y1=0;
    w = 0;
    h=0;
    x3 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
    width1=0;
    height1 = 0;
    x4 = 0;
    y4 = 0;
    x5 = 0;
    y5 = 0;
    width2=0;
    height2 = 0;
  window.getContentPane().removeAll();
  d.r = true;
  d.jfc = null;
  jp.removeActionListener(a1);
                    jp1.removeActionListener(a2);
                    brows.removeActionListener(a3);
                    pencil.removeActionListener(a4);

 }


  public void mousePressed( MouseEvent event )
  {
   if(d.r==false){if(this.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {

        dragging = true;

    }}else{

   if(shape == null)
       shape = new Rectangle();

   if(!but.isShowing()){
 but.setVisible(true);
  }

   mousePressedX = event.getX();
    mousePressedY = event.getY();
   c =0;
   but.setText("0x0");
  size.setText("0x0");

  startPoint = endPoint = event.getPoint();
  if(m==1){
              sz.setVisible(false);
              }else{sz.setVisible(true);}

  but.setBounds(x1, y1-30, 100, 30);
  p.setVisible(false);

  window.getContentPane().removeAll();
  window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

  d.et.displayImage = null;
  d.et.OSC = null;
  d.et.currentColor = Color.BLACK;
  d.et.currentTool = EditTool.Tool.CURVE;
  }}


 public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent event )
  {
   if(d.r == false){
       dragging = false;
       endPoint = event.getPoint();
   if(x1<x2 &&y1<y2 ){ 
              p.setBounds(x3+width1,y3+height1-200,50,200);}



              p.setVisible(true);
   }
   else{
        d.r =false;
        endPoint = event.getPoint();
               c=1;
              if(x1<x2 &&y1<y2 ){ 

              p.setBounds(x2+10,y2-200,50,200);}
              else if(x1 == x2 && y1<y2){p.setBounds(x2-60,y2-200,50,200);}
              else if(x1 == x2 && y1==y2){p.setBounds(x2-60,y2,50,200);}
              else if(x1 < x2 && y1==y2){p.setBounds(x2+10,y2,50,200);}

              if(m==1){
              p.setVisible(false);
              }else{p.setVisible(true);}
             m=1; 
    x1 = 0;
    y1=0;
    w = 0;
    h=0;
    shape.reshape(x3, y3, width1, height1);

    a1 = new ActionListener(){
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){



    try {               x1 = (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                         y1 = (startPoint.y < endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                       x2 = (startPoint.x > endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                       y2 = (startPoint.y > endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                        width = (x2-2 - x1) + 1;
                        height = (y2-2 - y1) + 1;
         Date date = new Date();
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_h_mm_ss_a");
         String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

                       robot = new Robot();

                   BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x3, y3, width1,height1));

                              if( movieFolder == null){
                                  movieFolder = null;

                    if(d.jfc == null)
                       d.jfc = new JFileChooser();

    d.jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    int r = d.jfc.showSaveDialog(d.jfc);

    if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        movieFolder = d.jfc.getSelectedFile();

    }}
                   ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(movieFolder,"screenShot"+formattedDate+".png"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                   
           }
                       };
    jp.addActionListener(a1);
                       a2 = new ActionListener(){
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){


                       p.setVisible(false);
                       but.setVisible(false);
                       d.main.dispose();

                       x1 = 0;
                       y1=0;
                       w = 0;
                       h=0;
                       x3 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
    width1=0;
    height1 = 0;
                    jp.removeActionListener(a1);
                    jp1.removeActionListener(a2);
                    brows.removeActionListener(a3);
                    pencil.removeActionListener(a4);
                    movieFolder = null;

                       }
                       };
                       jp1.addActionListener(a2);
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                       a3 = new ActionListener(){

                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    try {               x1 = (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                         y1 = (startPoint.y < endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                       x2 = (startPoint.x > endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                       y2 = (startPoint.y > endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                        width = (x2-2 - x1) + 1;
                        height = (y2-2 - y1) + 1;
         Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_h_mm_ss_a");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

                       robot = new Robot();

                   BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x3, y3, width1,height1));


                                  movieFolder = null;

                    if(d.jfc == null)
                       d.jfc = new JFileChooser();

    d.jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    int r = d.jfc.showSaveDialog(d.jfc);

    if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        movieFolder = d.jfc.getSelectedFile();

    }
                   ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(movieFolder,"screenShot"+formattedDate+".png"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

                       }
                       };
                       brows.addActionListener(a3);

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                      a4 = new ActionListener(){
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){


                    Date date1 = new Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_h_mm_ss_a");
                    String formattedDate1 = sdf1.format(date1);
                try {               x4 = (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                         y4 = (startPoint.y < endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                       x5 = (startPoint.x > endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                       y5 = (startPoint.y > endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                        width2 = (x5-2 - x4) + 1;
                        height2 = (y5-2 - y4) + 1;


                       robot = new Robot();

                   BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x3+1, y3+1, width1,height1));

                               if( movieFolder == null){
                                  movieFolder = null;

                    if(d.jfc == null)
                       d.jfc = new JFileChooser();

    d.jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

    int r = d.jfc.showSaveDialog(d.jfc);

    if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        movieFolder = d.jfc.getSelectedFile();

    }}
                   ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(movieFolder,"screenShot"+formattedDate1+".png"));


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                   

    x1 = 0;
    y1=0;
    w = 0;
    h=0;
    x3 = 0;
    y3 = 0;
    width1=0;
    height1 = 0;
    x4 = 0;
    y4 = 0;
    x5 = 0;
    y5 = 0;
    width2=0;
    height2 = 0;



                MainIconPage d1 = new MainIconPage();
                       p.setVisible(false);
                       but.setVisible(false);
                       d1.main.dispose();
                    try {

                        cl = movieFolder.toURL().toString().substring(6)+"/screenShot"+formattedDate1+".png";
                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CropScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                 //System.out.println(d.bs);
                    if(d.et == null){

                    d.et=new EditTool(cl);
                    d.et.s1 = "";}
                    else{d.et.s1 = "";
                    d.et.repaint();
                    d.et.cl(cl);
                    }

                        jp.removeActionListener(a1);
                           jp1.removeActionListener(a2);
                           brows.removeActionListener(a3);
                    pencil.removeActionListener(a4);

                    }



                       };
                       pencil.addActionListener(a4);




  }}


  public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent event )
   {
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
  }


  public void mouseExited( MouseEvent event )
  {
    mousePosition.setText( "Mouse outside window" );
  }


  public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent event )
  {if(d.r ==false){
  if(dragging) {
     endPoint = event.getPoint();
          Point p1 = event.getPoint();
         Rectangle r = component.shape;
         int type = component.getCursor().getType();
         int dx = p1.x - r.x;
          int dy = p1.y - r.y;
        switch(type) {
            case Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                int height=height1 = Math.abs(r.height - dy);
                x3=r.x;
                y3=r.y+dy;
                shape.reshape(r.x, r.y+dy, r.width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                int width =width1 = Math.abs(r.width - dx);
                height=height1 = Math.abs(r.height - dy);
                x3=r.x+dx;
                y3=r.y+dy;
                shape.reshape(r.x+dx, r.y+dy, width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                width =width1 = Math.abs(r.width - dx);
                x3=r.x+dx;
                y3=r.y;
                shape.reshape(r.x+dx, r.y, width, r.height);
                break;
            case Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                width =width1 = Math.abs(r.width - dx);
                height=height1 = Math.abs(dy);
                x3=r.x+dx;
                y3=r.y;
                shape.reshape(r.x+dx, r.y, width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                height=height1 = Math.abs(dy);
                x3=r.x;
                y3=r.y;
                shape.reshape(r.x, r.y, r.width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                width =width1 = Math.abs(dx);
                height=height1 = Math.abs(dy);
                x3=r.x;
                y3=r.y;
                shape.reshape(r.x, r.y, width, height);
                break;
            case Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                width =width1 = Math.abs(dx);
                x3=r.x;
                y3=r.y;
                shape.reshape(r.x, r.y, width, r.height);
                break;
            case Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR:
                width =width1 = Math.abs(dx);
                height=height1 = Math.abs(r.height - dy);
                x3=r.x;
                y3=r.y+dy;
                shape.reshape(r.x, r.y+dy, width, height);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("unexpected type: " + type);
        }
        if(c == 0){endPoint = event.getPoint();}
   x1 = (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                         y1 = (startPoint.y < endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                       x2 = (startPoint.x > endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                       y2 = (startPoint.y > endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                        width = (x2-2 - x1) + 1;
                        height = (y2-2 - y1) + 1;
                        p.setVisible(true);
                        if(x1<x2 &&y1<y2 ){ 
              but.setBounds(x3, y3-30, 100, 30);
                        p.setBounds(x3+width1,y3+height1-200,50,200);}


              shape.reshape(x3, y3, width1, height1);      
              but.setText(width1+"x"+height1);
              repaint();

    }
  }
  else{    
   int mouseDraggedX = event.getX();
  int mouseDraggedY = event.getY();
  width1 = Math.abs(mouseDraggedX - mousePressedX); 
  height1 = Math.abs(mouseDraggedY - mousePressedY); 

  x3 = Math.min(mouseDraggedX, mousePressedX);
  y3 = Math.min(mouseDraggedY, mousePressedY);
  m=0;


  if(c == 0){endPoint = event.getPoint();}
  x1 = (startPoint.x < endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                         y1 = (startPoint.y < endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                       x2 = (startPoint.x > endPoint.x) ? startPoint.x : endPoint.x;
                       y2 = (startPoint.y > endPoint.y) ? startPoint.y : endPoint.y;
                        width = (x2-2 - x1) + 1;
                        height = (y2-2 - y1) + 1;
                        if(x1<x2 &&y1<y2 ){ 
              but.setBounds(x3, y3-30, 100, 30);}
              shape.reshape(x3, y3, width1, height1);      
              but.setText(width+"x"+height);
              repaint();

  }}


    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent event )
   {
   if(d.r == false){
    Point p = event.getPoint();
    if(!isOverRect(p)) {
        if(component.getCursor() != Cursor.getDefaultCursor()) {

            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        }
        return;
    }
    int outcode = getOutcode(p);
    Rectangle r = component.shape;
    switch(outcode) {
        case Rectangle.OUT_TOP:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - r.y) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_TOP + Rectangle.OUT_LEFT:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - r.y) < PROX_DIST &&
               Math.abs(p.x - r.x) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.NW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_LEFT:
            if(Math.abs(p.x - r.x) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_LEFT + Rectangle.OUT_BOTTOM:
            if(Math.abs(p.x - r.x) < PROX_DIST &&
               Math.abs(p.y - (r.y+r.height)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.SW_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_BOTTOM:
            if(Math.abs(p.y - (r.y+r.height)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_BOTTOM + Rectangle.OUT_RIGHT:
            if(Math.abs(p.x - (r.x+r.width)) < PROX_DIST &&
               Math.abs(p.y - (r.y+r.height)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_RIGHT:
            if(Math.abs(p.x - (r.x+r.width)) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        case Rectangle.OUT_RIGHT + Rectangle.OUT_TOP:
            if(Math.abs(p.x - (r.x+r.width)) < PROX_DIST &&
               Math.abs(p.y - r.y) < PROX_DIST) {
                component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(
                                    Cursor.NE_RESIZE_CURSOR));
            }
            break;
        default:    
            component.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
    }

  }
  }


  private int getOutcode(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.shape.clone();
    r.grow(-PROX_DIST, -PROX_DIST);
    return r.outcode(p.x, p.y);        
  }


  private boolean isOverRect(Point p) {
    Rectangle r = (Rectangle)component.shape.clone();
    r.grow(PROX_DIST, PROX_DIST);
    return r.contains(p);
 }
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
 super.paintComponent(g);

  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g2.setStroke(dashed);

 if(x1 ==0 && y1 == 0){
  g2.dispose();
  }
 else{
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 g2.draw(shape);
 g2.setColor(Color.black);
 Area area = new Area();

  area.add(new Area(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight())));

 g2.setColor(Color.BLACK.brighter());

int width = getWidth() - 1;
int height = getHeight() - 1;

int openWidth = 200;
int openHeight = 200;

int x = (width - openWidth) / 2;
int y = (height - openHeight) / 2;


area.subtract(new Area(shape));



g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
g2.fill(area);
g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.5f));
g2.fillRect(x3-8, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3-8, (y3+height1/2)-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3-8, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect((x3+width1/2)-8, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, y3-8, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect((x3+width1/2)-8, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, y3+height1, 8, 8);
g2.fillRect(x3+width1, (y3+height1/2)-8, 8, 8);
g2.dispose();
 }

 }


boolean selectedExistingRectangle(int x, int y) {
        return shape != null && shape.contains(x, y);
    }

    void setRectangle(int x, int y) {
        //shape = new Rectangle(x-(size/2), y-(size/2), 0, 0);
        shape.reshape(x, y, width, height);

        repaint();
    }
    public static String removeExtension(String s) {

String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String filename;


int lastSeparatorIndex = s.lastIndexOf(separator);
if (lastSeparatorIndex == -1) {
    filename = s;
} else {
    filename = s.substring(lastSeparatorIndex + 1);
}


int extensionIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
if (extensionIndex == -1)
    return filename;

return filename.substring(0, extensionIndex);
 }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a bug in code you're not showing us. Have you gone through the Swing graphics tutorials yet? If so, then I assume that you're not drawing directly in the JFrame, right? For more help, please show code, please give more information on the problem.

Comment: i have added the full code in body of my question

Comment: any one can help me please.